# Find the discrete logarithm

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, integer

## Task

Write a program/function that when given 3 positive integers \$a, b\$ and \$m\$ as input outputs a positive integer \$x\$ such that \$a^x\equiv b\ (\text{mod}\ m)\$ or that no such \$x\$ exists.

A reference implementation can be found [here](https://tio.run/##bZDRboQgEEXf@Yp5ExNqFHBXm9hP6Bc0adyKuyQKBGjqfr1lsE33oRMlmXvPzA24e7xZI/Z9UjNMOnx4FdX7Yq90ZHBhsNqpfCaQarYeNtAG/GiuijaPHpaewdkvHNsOC4YBLn8@Vlr@6Q1s5KF5tUbtenXWRwj3QAgGLdoozEpCFeKkTd6jjWMwmgBDBiofoteOFm@mKKvgFh1pAU8vUJRI/1wgwevoqDaR4YJfjiWqJJkLQWF29PS/ByjzRVLq3tQM8G9rDGnI0aeD11nhh5I@fsZeciLahEuUpOhQ6wRpuuaUZk68ZyDqc0Y5F0SIOumy4TLNiLbPIT0aEvVsihyET/YN).

## Constraints

You can expect \$a\$ and \$b\$ to be less than \$m\$.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins.

## Sample Testcases

```
# a, b, m -> x

10, 10, 50 -> 1
10, 100, 200 -> 2
10, 1, 127 -> 42
35, 541, 1438 -> 83
35, 541, 1438 -> 1519
1816, 2629, 3077 -> 223
3306, 4124, 5359 -> 1923
346, 406, 430 -> None
749430, 2427332, 2500918 -> 8025683
3442727916, 3990620294, 6638635157 -> 5731137125
```

**Note:** in the third testcase the solution cannot be 0 since the solution has to be a positive number

Comment: Mathematica has a built in that does exactly this...  `MultiplicativeOrder`   https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiplicativeOrder.html

Comment: The restriction against an output of zero feels to me like a corner case gotcha.

Comment: @xnor It indeed is. Without that edge case, both my 05AB1E and MathGolf answers would have been a byte shorter by using a list in the range \$[0,m]\$ instead of \$[1,m]\$ and removing the final increment to convert the 0-based to a 1-based index. Then again, using just positive integers for \$a,b,m,x\$ is a reasonable additional requirement, even if it doesn't add much to the core challenge itself except for a minor edge case.

Comment: Could you add a few more test cases that fall within `2**53-1` please?

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>59</s> <s>53</s></sup> 51 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

Saved 2 bytes thanks [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)!!!

```c
p;x;f(a,b,m){for(p=a,x=1;p-b&&++x<m;)p=p*a%m;x%=m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHbboMwDIbv@xQWEhWUVAsJ9KCU3Ux7irWaAoWNi9AIuIhW8ezMHKJ2XZH8x/D7s5GTrb@yrO@1MKLwJEmJ8q/FpfZ0IolJQqHX6XIZBOaghK8TvZKuEsZNlOh6JcvK8@G6AHyyb1mvoP44QQJX52je2dHs3zBih8D9O3c6MRJl1UKbN@2nnKCQErDBYzx34QYzTgeNNo9Uek8NQiCOUNiG7QlEIYtQ6T9MTVhMCRsptkWJ@A5n0C3mMY8HnNM7MDc6N21@HlEciUOwBGPHMWUo4X5Qy@D@wBvAsjrnBhkq5vQATfmTXwrPtvRf5g9Y7gsIgrHOLtX@gMQe86pG/yT@2Km106e2srZ6ajdo26u/ObpGr/Ac90xgCli/Duo2xwqvVBJICSgCDcFbxx7JbU3TlNPcrVt0/S8)

Inputs positive integers \$a,b,m\$ with \$a,b<m\$.
Outputs a positive integer \$x\$ such that \$a^x\equiv b\ (\text{mod}\ m)\$ or \$0\$ if no such \$x\$ exists.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHbboMwDIbv@xQWUiUYqRYS6GFptotpT7FWU6CwcRGKAhfRKp6dmUPUbiuS/xh@fzZystVnlvW9EbWwovAVSYkOLsXZ@LVUxEoqbBjutahl/aCWOjCyljJ90dI@UWFE12tVVn4AlwXgk30p8wDm/QgSLt7BvrGD3b1iJB6B23fudWIkyqqFNm/aDzVBESXggid4bqM1ZpwOGq//UuktNQiBJEZha7YjEEcsRqX/MD1hCSVspNgGJeZbnEE3mCc8GXBOb8Dc1rlt89OI4kgcgiUYW44pQ4l2gzoGdwj@AJbVKbfIUDGne2jK7/xc@K5l8Dh/wPJAQBiOdW6p7gcU9phXNfpH8ctOnZ3etbWz9V27Qdtd/9WpDXqF7y1PBKaA1fOgy@ZQ4ZUqAikBTaAheOvYQ17XNE05zt26Rdf/AA) without the ```p=``` at the end, if it's Ok to output ```m``` for 'no solution exists'.

Comment: or [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHbboMwDIbv@xQWUiUYqRYS6GFptotpT7FWU6CwcREaARfRKp6dmUPUbiuS/xh@fzZystVnlvV9LYywovAVSYkOLsW59o1UxEoqbBjutTDSPKilDoyU6YuW9omKrteqrPwALgvAJ/tS9QPU70eQcPEO9o0d7O4VI/EI3L5zrxMjUVYttHnTfqgJiigBFzzBcxutMeN00Hj9l0pvqUEIJDEKW7MdgThiMSr9h@kJSyhhI8U2KDHf4gy6wTzhyYBzegPm1uS2zU8jiiNxCJZgbDmmDCXaDeoY3B/4A1hWp9wiQ8Wc7qEpv/Nz4buWweP8AcsDAWE41rmluh9Q2GNe1egfxS87dXZ619bO1nftBm139VfH1OgVvrc8EZgCVs@DLptDhVeqCKQENIGG4K1jD3ld0zTlOHfrFl3/Aw).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice idea but don't see how outputting `m` could possibly be valid for signalling 'no solution exist'.

Comment: I kind-of thought that ```m``` could be considered equivalent to zero when using mod-m arithmetic...  In any case, it's an impossible-to-obtain value for the solution that could be pre-declared to represent 'no solution exists'.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Sure, but the kicker's that it's a positive integer *and* it's not a solution. It requires extra work *outside* of the function to deduce what the output actually means.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHdboMwDIXv@xQWUisoqRYS6I9SdjPtKdZqChQ2LkIj4CJaxbMzB4jWbUXyweH4s5GTbz7yfBi0MKL0JcmICm7ltfF1KolJI6E32WoVhuaoRKBTvZZLJcw6ted@ULKq/QBuC8An/5TNGpq3M6Rw807mlZ3M4QUj8Qjcn7nXi5Go6g66ou3e5QRFlIALnuB7H20x49RqvP1LZfeUFQJJjMK27EAgjliMSv9hasISSthIsR1KzPc4g@4wT3hicU7vwMLownTFZURxJA7BEow9x5ShRAerjsENgm/Bqr4UBhkq5vQIbfVVXEvftQye5g9YHggIw7HOLdX9gMQe86pG/yx@2Zmzs4e2crZ6aLdou8v/cXSDXul7ywuBKWDzbHXZnmq8UkkgI6AItARvHXukP2uappznbv2iH74B)?

Comment: @Arnauld Bravo - was trying to untangle testing for answer and end to no avail - thanks! :D

Comment: That's great.  And, now that ```m``` isn't changed, you can do this for [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHbboMwDIbv@xQWUisoqRYS6EEpu5n2FGs1hdPGRWgEXESreHZmDlG7rkj@Y/j92chJN19p2vdaGFG4kiREedfiUrs6lsTEgdCbZLXyfXNUwtOxXsulEiY2qF2vZFm5HlwXgE/6Les11B9niOHqnMw7O5nDG0bkELh/504nRqKsWmjzpv2UExRQAjZ4hOc@2GLG6aDh9pFK7qlBCEQhCtuyA4EwYCEq/YepCYsoYSPFdigh3@MMusM84tGAc3oH5kbnps2zEcWROARLMPYcU4YSHAa1DC4Q3AEsqyw3yFAxp0doyp/8Uri2pfcyf8ByT4Dvj3V2qfYHJPaYVzX6Z/HHTqydPLWVtdVTu0Hb3v3N0TV6hessMwJTwOZ10GVzqvBKJYGEgCLQELx17BHf1jRNOc/dukXX/wI)

Comment: @Dominic van Essen And we're there! Very nice - thanks! :D

Comment: Do you need the last semicolon before the `)`?

Comment: @Floris Yes, it's part of the syntax of a `for` loop..

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```python
def f(a,b,m,x=1):a**x%m==b<exit(x);x<m<f(a,b,m,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBNboMwEIX3PsUoVaVAnQhs8tuQXbe9gwNDagkbZDstnD4dkzSNhJH95nszz@7H8NVZcdWm71wAP3pGa@kxOKwuzuvOttroMM@zNF0n1xobaOaKn7jhQ5kne5Wmw6spy9MBB8KG5H04mMMDecuT597sBbT1AVUNXQOqChfVtiNEa9D2zMETTIJT2iMoC@hc58jlO/hBqEgJ6AOYSxt030bFo2cx1X38nt3NH0OFfaD8JDLWdA5abZHGw3TBUGtLLOWEEweTcGrQYxWwhhKM6uf4rVo@eZa@b6n3bHGcJQl75h5b6p4xCG6kln/vQyg49JSUyCz6YqD/XKA84P4ZwqVB79UZGfRO23Cv8AfxP/GaZxziWmWwOELObmf6iWxSxE2hT2ziuRBMrggvolTIbdS2kuXbfE2etdhxkNlmQoWQTMqM9CIXBXnkajcN2cVCEfWpKKdBn53FXw)

A recursive function that simply tests all exponents from \$1\$ to \$m\$. Returns through exit code: a positive exponent \$x\$, or \$0\$ if no such \$x\$ exists.

Comment: `a==b<c` with side effects is definitely evil syntax

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>38</s>  33 bytes

Expects `(a,m)(b)` as 3 BigInts. Throws *RangeError* if there's no solution.

```javascript
(a,m,x=m)=>g=b=>a**--x%m-b?g(b):x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5Na4NAEAbgu79iLoWdsJr9MtGWtVDooZdeegweVqvWEt1ilmIp@e12TRVCLi/LPPMu82m@zakc2i8X9va9mmo9EUM7OuoOddboQmdmswnD8a4Li8eGFHg/Tg@HAOAAwBmFNWMGOYXtFviVcTanYKuJ6x7weUPsF1MLytiPY@WRK5ksmMgZecJ3FMROpBQk269NIS4qJfOquFAUYhmn6z3pP4NUnkGxS0p/Esz8avsqyIOotsOzKT8IORgKBYUuR9AZ/IIbfnyWtj/ZYxUdbUNq8tQ2L70jBikszw5xnRaICGcojfPfVXhTriJn39zQ9g2Z1844/QE)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

Expects `(a,m)(b)` as 3 BigInts. Returns *false* if there's no solution.

NB: This version always returns the smallest solution.

```javascript
(a,m,x=0n)=>g=b=>a**++x%m-b?x<m&&g(b):x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7NbsIwDAfwe5/Cl6EEAuQT2m3ppEk77LIXqHpIuraASDIBmvr2XcoaCR/@svyzJZ/Mr7k2l@PPbe3Ddzt2ekSGODJo6rEue211aZbL1Wp4cmv7Nry6xaJHFj8P40uVAVQAjBJIqSjUBLZbYA/G6JScJuOPd8CmDb6fTc4oVBwrGZFJkc@YiwlZznYE@I4XBATdp0vO7yoEjSoZlwSUUEX6p/hnEDIySHpPEV@Cib@Cb7M623Th8mGaA0KVIWAJuBqDLqEJ/hrO7eYcetSh92P/6W/IYAJz6zBOU4tjjX8)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Lm¹%³k>
```

Inputs in the order \$m,a,b\$; outputs `0` if no \$x\$ is found.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ/fQTtVDm7Pt/v83NDG24DI25TI1MQQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCaHHEf5/cCNXibLv/Ov@jow0NdIDI1CBWB8I00DEygHF0DI3MgUxjUx1TEyDHxNgCJGFhaKZjZGZkqWNsYA6WNjYw0zExNDLRMTU2tQQJmAD5IDFjg9hYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L        # Push a list of values `x` in the range [1, (implicit) input `m`]
 m       # Take the (implicit) input `a` to the power of each of these `x`
  ¹%     # Take each modulo the first input `m`
    ³k   # Get the 0-based index of the first occurrence of the third input `b`
         # (-1 if there are none)
      >  # And increase it by 1 to make it a 1-based index
         # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 23 bytes

```apl
{⍺(∊×⍳⍨)(⍺⍺|⍵×⊢)⌂traj⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc89CsJAEAXg3lNMmRTC7s5uTGobbdULrCQK4h9ioaiNgkhwRQuxsrGysxAbS73JXCSuphAkwmNgho8Ho/vtfDjW7V4zH42GUTeMwiSZkLk7tIqfBzJXMmfXsQebKZmbvcUnl9bz4UC37D5LGrTcktlQvHhckJY72uyrlaKdtVK5mmioQwcsAc7eUQzIHIHn6uB0oOGCzv0QBoKlSPxFwEXhQ2S2QQVKWiXR/zAfs6t87oHwRADICmmhENkUkXkguZCgUAXpD8E/Ky19c0z/YF/1Ag)

Dyalog APL can't handle large integers, so a modulo should be performed after each iteration.

#### How it works

```apl
{⍺(∊×⍳⍨)(⍺⍺|⍵×⊢)⌂traj⍵}  ⍝ dop; ⍵ ⍺ ⍺⍺ ← a b m
        (      )⌂traj    ⍝ Collect all iterations until duplicate is found
                     ⍵   ⍝   starting from a:
            ⍵×⊢          ⍝     Multiply a
         ⍺⍺|             ⍝     Modulo m
 ⍺(  ⍳⍨)                 ⍝ Find the 1-based index of b in the result,
   ∊×                    ⍝   changing to 0 if not found
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,m,x=0{(a**x+=1)%m==b&&x||x<m&&redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Ba4MwGIbv/RUf7WbUpjYmsdWydIeywy4dlN2cDF2VFbSKWnCov93GINsgyeF53vf7Ut6inyERw2of4ghnuBGk1UPTbJbCNh4zISJNa7queco0rYzPeT/4MwBkEwzjdQis9mAj/AflQ4nC9B@Wh25HyCfKHNnmI@fMHYXLprhrb@SIDfUwMLJVJUonyRiRktuUyzZzPLXd@7V8lCrB1A@O@TVGs8CKw69vaKGrOyhudQXzRVuCgMQ3a6sq0kutI4wMKwsLXdvV@efFCHpYtOj1iOB2TeOqApkXUPtIjQzgGZIwrWLYSbb@OC8f1oE1FvvD2@n0cnifQz/cAQ)

The logic is straightforward: increment the exponent \$x\$ and return it if it satisfies the required equation, otherwise repeat while \$x\$ is less than \$m\$. Outputs the smallest solution for \$x\$, or `false` if no solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/)+gmp, <s>47</s> 46 bytes

Or only [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc7LCsIwEIXhfd@jkIFBJrdehL6FayWptQaaVtK60JePcadCXJ9vfibEydlgwoON/gbF2a19GLbhNC1jFy/3ud/cMjODFj14s/VXdkBzZHzvoSx911mInzfMrDvrxifjBMgJNX03f3ZCQX8FclFndqkBtUpCySaXaHgFKCrRoqQ6G5KUlOJCoZa6zSn1RlShkunjoogv) by requiring input in the form of `bigz` big integer.

```r
function(a,b,m)match(T,as.bigz(a)^(1:m)%%m==b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwFET3@Y/CDVwk77ZC/8K1ktRaA01b0rrQn48RN1qFWc3hDBPT4F208Q59mCk5@6WN3dqdhqlv0uU2tqufRrDoMNBg1/YKB7TLzvn@AZYege8DLYrQNI6mTxk4wxzNvjffNUPB/gHkotzUUqNWGShZbYWKGxRG1ChZ@aNJZlBxoVBLXW@hyuzFZT5BSHoC)

Comment: arguably, you can just use ordinary integers and save yourself the call to `as.bigz`

Comment: and it's more efficient to use `which(...)` rather than `match(T,...)` (you will get NA if there isn't one)

Comment: @JDL Unfortunately, without the ```bigz``` big integer, it fails by going out of the integer range for all except the first (smallest) two test cases.

Comment: @JDL and the reason that I ended-up using ```match(T,...)``` instead of ```which(...)``` is because many discrete logarithms have more-than-one solution (for instance, the fourth test case), so ```which``` needs an extra ```[1]``` at the end to only output one of them, which makes it longer.

Comment: `a*1` would turn `a` into a double-precision — is that big enough?

Comment: @JDL Unfortunately, not even nearly big enough!  A double-precision float isn't  big enough to handle 3306^5359 (the last example) at all (R simply evaluates it as ```Inf```).  And, worse, the need to take the modulo means that all calculations need to be accurate to the last integer digit, which is a long way beyond the precision of a floating-point representation!

Comment: The most-elegant solution - I think - is to perform the modulo at every step of the exponentiation.  That way, the numbers never get too big.  This is what I've attempted in the other 'base R only' answer, so have a look & see if you can beat that one (or improve it!)...

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
_╒k▬\%=)
```

Port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206700/52210), so also:
Inputs in the order \$m,a,b\$; outputs `0` if no \$x\$ is found.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LYg7DkBAFAD7d4rXKHTvuyjcRCIaJIjGSSScwqlcZC2RTDEzS7eNwzr3Mbb3sU/3eTVZncfohPwCQr8RsBSfApuWqI5uDEpFuiUHlCAVuHqFqhTQWAxMCdVSUHgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
_         # Duplicate the first (implicit) input `m`
 ╒        # Pop one and push a list in the range [1, `m`]
  k       # Push the second input `a`
   ▬      # For each value `x` in the list, take `a` to the power `x`
    \     # Swap so the originally duplicated `m` is at the top of the stack
     %    # Take modulo-`m` on each value in the list
      =   # Get the first 0-based index of the value that equals the third (implicit)
          # input `b` (-1 if there are none)
       )  # And increase it by 1 to make it a 1-based index
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 97 bytes

```java
(a,b,m)->{for(int x=0;x++<m;)if(a.modPow(b.valueOf(x),b.valueOf(m)).equals(b))return x;return-1;}
```

\$a\$ and \$b\$ are both `java.math.BigInteger`; \$m\$ and the output \$x\$ are both `int`.
Outputs `-1` if no \$x\$ is found.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVHLTsMwELz3K6ycbMWNnFcfCuXAjQMFqUfEYZ06JSVOSuKUoKpXPoBP5EfKJi3QqhWS5fXOzno94yWsob@cv@ziDKqK3EGab3qEpLlRZQKxItM27QAS0yWyHQ3m2blJF7fIWaiSAL8IS972aBZh/7aHW2XApDGZkpxMyI4Cl1yz/vUmKUraUpuJiBrbvtIRSxOKFxbzh@KNSmcNWa3uE9ow/pdoxhz1WkNWUclYqUxd5qSJ9oe@G213UTt0VcsMhx5mr4t0TjRqpDNTpvni8YkA2ws0qjLUFRxXKLpHH2OCe@IM5a43PMb8kIcBooE/OqGO3AH3Bt6Y@2J42uCLAQ9cL@ChH45PKgEW2qIvzgzsRHSs1jXobP4xe69l9l4ZpZ2iNs4KZZospxZMLBtsi0uMEqPGqG2LfH18ovOWnTuXv/fXcGD837pk@J2Hx2533w)

**Explanation:**

```java
(a,b,m)->{            // Method with 2 BigInteger & integer parameters and integer return
  for(int x=0;x++<m;) //  Loop `x` in the range (0,m]:
    if(a.modPow(b.valueOf(x),b.valueOf(m))
                      //   If `a` to the power `x`, modulo `m`
       .equals(b))    //   equals `b`:
      return x;       //    Return `x` as result
  return-1;}          //  If the loop has ended without result, return -1 instead
```

Answer (score 2):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), <strike>58</strike> 50 bytes

```
define f(a,b,m){for(;x<m;)if(a^++x%m==b)return(x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxLCsMgEED3PYWbghIXo6P5kOQqhdoqZGEK0oJQenYzWkrBEd6bx7hbKXcftt2zwK/SySje4ZH4nJc4i43cpevyOa6rE8k/X2nnWXxKCVyBZHUsiNOP6NPwZ3p6qISWOlPZ4NjWo@qp7fUkGcLwjRDIGaUNxWin5kxVzSPdPQA)

This just tries the integers from 1 to `m`, and outputs the first one
which satisfies being a discrete log. Otherwise, the function returns
`0` (default return value).

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzbCgIhEEDf@wpfAmV9GB3dC5u/EmQp7IMbSIEQfbuNRgSOcM4cxl9rvYW47YFFfpFeJvGK98yLg7Wc0io20udhKMfknBc5PJ5550W8a41cgWRtLIjDj@jT8Gd6emqEljrT2ODc17MaqR31IhnC9I0QyBmlDcVol@5MU90j3f0A) by syntax guesswork...

Comment: @DominicvanEssenThanks. And we can even omit the `x=0` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

Takes in a list of `[A,M,B]`, output is either `X` or `false`. The `[3306, 5359, 4124]` test case times out on TIO, but returns the correct result locally. First Brachylog answer, so probably not the best solution. :-)

```
bhM>.>0&h;.^;M%~t?∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/PynD107PzkAtw1ovztpXta7E/lHH8v@qCtGGBjoKpkBsaBDLBeUaGYD5CAFDI3MgAeYamwJZJsYWQE0muEQMLQzNdBSMDcyBuozMjCwhyowNgIKmxqaWOgomhkYmEEEToJiJMdAKEwOz2P@YOv9HAQA)

#### How it works

```
bhM>.>0&h;.^;M%~t?∧
bhM                 set the second item to M
   >.>0             output must be between M and 0
       &h           input's first item (A)
         ;.^        A^output
            ;M%     A^output mod M
               ~t?  must unify with the tail from the input (B)
                  ∧ return the output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
(a#m)b=last$0:[x|x<-[1..m],mod(a^x-b)m==0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZFbb5tAEIXf@RVTkgdQCMXGzq3ltVKl9CK1Uh8cW1rMBFbeC9ldbCL5v7uz4EskY7Fnzpz5dmiY3aAQh0PErmRcFoJZd509Lfp9//V2MUlTuUykriK26m/LWBZFtjw4tM5CAYsAIJpkCfhnnsXJ5Ux/0@yjQr/p/XjO5@SeeWWWPxwtD5M76ribPiaQZ/cnY56ROptMZ9SQzx@P6syLQyXP4mUQeByIWAJlAjImrkqTT6CDng4Rgysvl6S1nfvjDFxDZBu9AxbDzQ2EL24FoX@L@Cu1fC4gA9eggsHUAwqLEP7UCsNTQ1EcOwZLeZIj2tTHghwL8YsLaTql@zoBraCPQQKleKGk1/3ew54nj6DPCsLfzNpwRLiI3xgXn8IgkIyr030v1X/MKK7qJx8F47eqNCjtYK1lS3tB8Q5bNPz1fbAYfOu4QQLBhm25NhBhWqfAHbQ0HS3siAmpg/C4Jb/rjMIqgR13je7cMYxm@jyD3sRVhRSpNFgtOse1@uIDK01xHuU8n7kjxBgKWya6IYFBqy13fEsn5bBGEyfAVAWWqzUOTUzZHVHxMbJT/K3DBNYNrjcehtW0Hzvm15Sjhm3Amvk7nUkaFG0Kz8zUPkrRHmk2XUJL7hwBOQ0bxNbTd3QpM8T9/f4LHJcIgpMt9Z9XsvbHOGDYeXD4Dw)

The function `(a # m) b` returns a positive integer `x` such that `a ^ x == b (mod m)`. If no such `x` exists, it returns `0`. This is done by the brute force method.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

```r
function(a,b,m){for(i in c(1:m,0))if((T=(a*T)%%m)==b)break;i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc67DoJAEAXQnq@gIZkxU8y@eGj2L@gNIJiNAsmKlfHb17V0MZnqntyb8eHiHoMft/F8X682TM9l2Ny6QEc9zfiaVg8ud0s@gDjOxIhuAmgtdIcWi2JGa3vs/djdTu79swWCKZ5hzPYxk@R/QEJWSawMGR1Bqzot1KIkWcqGFFe7muKStJCajDJNijra11V8IsvCBw)

The base form of R doesn't support arbitrary-precision arithmetic (see [my other 'R+gmp' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206694/find-the-discrete-logarithm/206703#206703) for a solution using the 'gmp' library that allows this).
But, pleasingly, the step-by-step calculation of `(a^x)mod m` comes-out at only 14 bytes longer than the brute-force approach, and it's *much* faster.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⊕⌕﹪ＸＮ…·¹θθＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMMzL7koNTc1ryQ1RcMtMy9Fwzc/pTQnXyMgvxyoGFmjpo4CUHFOaXFmWWpQYl56qoahjkKhpiaIAEkhqQQB6///DY3MFQwNFAz/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order `m, a, b` and outputs `0` if there is no solution. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ              Store `m`
        …·¹θ    Range from 1 to `m` inclusive
      ＸＮ        Take powers of `a`
     ﹪      θ   Reduce modulo `m`
    ⌕        Ｎ  Find index of `b`
   ⊕            Convert to 1-indexing
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 84 bytes

```
\d+
*
"$+"{`,(?=(_+))((_+),)+
,$.1*$3$&
)`^(_+),\1+
$1,
L$`.*(,_+)(,_+)+$(?<=\1)
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcgrDoAwDABQ32OMhrRrs1AQGAgX4AgLjAQEBkFwHH58zBPv3K79WCznuAp4cCjuTkpDT7Mw06eygGIwjw2WwGn6M5oAmsKIKXjSt34Eaej6aAxY1Dlb3apVag8) Sadly no test suite as this uses `"$+"`, and I can't figure out how to emulate that with multiple sets of inputs (Retina just crashes when I try). Takes input in the order `m, a, b` and produces no output if there is no solution. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
"$+"{`
)`
```

Repeat `m` times...

```
,(?=(_+))((_+),)+
,$.1*$3$&
```

... multiply the second number by the second last number and insert it between the first two numbers...

```
^(_+),\1+
$1,
```

... and reduce it modulo `m`.

```
L$`.*(,_+)(,_+)+$(?<=\1)
$#2
```

Count the position of the power matching `b` starting from the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 57 bytes

```
method(a,b,m,x :=1;for(i,1,m,if((x=x*a%m)==b,return i))0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7PCsIwDIfvPkUvQis9pEn/rMrexMuGKxbcJmPC3n5mgmjxIrQl/T7yS/K4JnGsxXntu/k6XmSjW93rhZk5pXGSWRv@5yTlUi@HZt@rum711M2PaRBZKVBrkga02K4DJe5THubbsHtTfhB@OR8M35Qc99uNW6r@EqYynsM9Ri0IQplGwM4atNxMLhbOburlqVgs2MiEIy0GIuTCAURTbmNZYojbaIoRPAJGHuI9VZ6ccZ811ic)